# display progress bar for a flash movie in webpage

Tags: php, flash, progress-bar, preloader

I have a flash movie about 10M to display in a webpage. I want to put a progress bar while it is loading to users view the page.I don't have access to source file to put some preloader inside it.

How can I do it ? is it possible to do it with php ?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe with javascript you can do something ....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating another flash movie that will load the first one while showing a progress bar.